# Count of Items in an Array within an Array on Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3

Let's say that I have some code like this:

```
let arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

How would I define a function that it takes in a number *i* such that it goes to the *i*th array in `arr` and it prints the number of elements?

For example, let's say the function is called `arrcount`. Then,
`arrcount(1) = 2`, `arrcount(2) = 3`, and `arrcount(3) = 5`.

Comment: What if you call `arrcount(3)` ? because there is only 3 Array elements in your array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need a function to achieve this:

```
arr[2].count // will return 5
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `arr[3]` and not `arr[2]`?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work

```
func countNumberOfItems(at index: Int, from arr: [Array<Any>]) -> Int? {
    if index < arr.count, let temp = arr[index] as? Array {
        return temp.count
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```